# How to use the JS variable in CodeBehind(aspx.cs) file?

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I use the variable of the Javascript method in my codebehind(aspx.cs) file??

Answer (score 1):

you can save variable's value in hidden field and set the hidden field as runat="server".

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of your javascrtipt variable to form element which is accessible at server side

```
<input id="hdnName" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Now set the value in js

```
var someJsVariable="Jon";
document.getElementById("hdnName").value=someJsVariable;
```

So in your sever side code (code behind), You can access the `hdnName` element and access it's value.

Comment: document.getElementById("hdnName").value=someJsVariable;

When I alert this value it shows the undefine.
alert(document.getElementById("hdnName").value);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I want to modify your code a little bit.
var someJsVariable="Jon";
document.getElementById("hdnName").value=someJsVariable;
If we follow this approach so we get the value of the hidden field at server side (""), so we should use the client Id like:
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnDeduction").value = someJsVariable;
This is only in the case when you are placing your hidden field in contentplaceholder or in something else which dynamically changes your hiddenfield id.